# How to click a form submit input which dont have onclick event but when it clicked in the page something will happen how to click it? in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a project with visual C# programming, and i want to connect it with a website and the website has a login button which named submit input, and i tried to create a button which work like this login button but i dont know which code to do when clicked and this is what i wrote and didnt work for me :-

```
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Document;
        HtmlElement email = null, pass = null;
        HtmlElementCollection col = doc.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("name").Equals("email")) email = element;
            if (element.GetAttribute("name").Equals("pass")) pass = element;
        }
        email.SetAttribute("value", txt1.Text);
        pass.SetAttribute("value", txt2.Text);
        HtmlElement login_form = doc.GetElementById("login_form");
        login_form.InvokeMember("post");
```

and i found the submit and named it login_button and tried another code :-

```
    login_button.InvokeMember("click");
```

but non of them worked for me, please how to fix it?

Comment: You need to define `non of them worked for me` better.  What errors are you receiving?

Comment: i described it, i want to login when i pressed the button but it wont happen with any of these codes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for all of you, i found the result i used one of them wrongly and i fixed that.

```
login_button.click();
```

i mean i didn't get this buttton which i want because of wrong finding the button.